# JavaScript works until I add this && statement.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do some A/B testing by sending 50% of traffic to an alternate advertising page.

Here is what I've got:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var country= geoip_country_code();
    var number= Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    if(number < 6 && country=="US") { window.location = "http://WEBSITE.com/PAGE-B" }
    else {  }
</script>
```

The only problem seems to be with my && statement.

If I change to fifth line to either

```
    if(number < 6) { window.location = "http://WEBSITE.com/PAGE-B" }
```

or

```
    if(country=="US") { window.location = "http://WEBSITE.com/PAGE-B" }
```

then it works like it should. I want these two if statements to work together though.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? Are you doing anything to verify the contents of `number` and `country`? Maybe you're just unlucky, and never get a number < 6.

Comment: (your syntax is fine)

Comment: It should work. How you know when number < 6 and country is "US"??

Comment: I live in the US, so that should always be true. If I change the else to redirect to somewhere else, the script still doesn't work with the && statement for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the location of the script was breaking it. I fixed it by making a fresh landing page, only using that JavaScript on it and and by having the else statement direct toward the page this script was originally on.